# Is it possible to add custom attributes to a group in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to cater for a broad set of auth and identity management requirements, homogenizing this area of functionality across different legacy applications, and looking into Azure AD B2C as an option.

It seems as though there may be a need for maintaining contact information on a group. For example, we may need to group users according to their 'reseller,' and we may wish to have additional info about the reseller within Azure AD B2C.

Is this possible in AD B2C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible to add custom attributes to a group in Azure AD B2C** using the same mechanism that's available in regular Azure AD via the Azure AD Graph: [Directory schema extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions).

Note that while you can use groups in Azure AD B2C, sending group claims in the token isn't yet supported, so you'll need to [make a separate call to the Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to obtain a user's group membership and details about the group. You can always vote for this ask in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Get user membership groups in the claims with AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b)