# How I allow multiple User in my Azure Active Directory tenant login with their Credential?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs-directive, azure-active-directory

how i login my app with multiple user which is in my Azure active Directory?

On azure I created Azure Active B2c Directory.
Then Register App.
Then create key.
Then Add User in Azure Active Directory.
Then assign that user to my Register app.

But while login with user email and password to my app I get Error.

AADSTS50020: User account  from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant  and cannot access the application  in that tenant.

I use web api in  backed.

and AngularJS in front end.

how i login my app with multiple user which is in my Azure active Directory?
also How i add role to User?

Comment: How did you add your MSA (Microsoft Account) into B2C tenant? Just use "+New guest user"?

Comment: No..+New User. and then assign Uset to app through option  Enterprice application.But User is not able to login application to which i assign.

Comment: Hi Heena, do you have a chance to look into my answer? If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Live.com doesn't belong to your tenant and it is a personal mail for the user. you need to add the user with let's say username@live.com to the tenant as a [guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal) and the user has to click the verify link which have been sent to his personal mail to become a guest user in Azure AD.

The [Assign administrator and non-administrator roles to users with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal) documents help you in adding roles to the user.

Comment: Thank you for Reply.But I Know that guest User is able to login application.and it happen in my case also.But I want to User which I added and assign to my enterprise app want to login with that User. For Role I want to assign app Role to User.

Comment: Hi @Heena, Please refer  Microsoft document which can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal

Answer (score 0):

Application roles are not currently supported in Azure AD B2C. See a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890027/define-application-specific-user-roles-in-azure-ad-b2c).

Azure AD B2C supports custom claims, which can be used to add app based roles. See [Define custom attributes in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes).

A [post on User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31997947-support-application-specific-roles-in-b2c) for your reference.